# Filtering Panda database imported from excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

i have a database in pandas imported from an excel file, this is the structure:
[image]

I need to calculate the previous rolling mean for HomeTeam and AwayTeam for every match, only for PSCH (odds for home win) and PSCA (odds for away win) and for current season,and i did this way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r"G:\SOCCER\datacouk.xlsx")

df['HomeMean'] = df.groupby(['Season', 'HomeTeam'])['PSCH'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())
df['AwayMean'] = df.groupby(['Season', 'AwayTeam'])['PSCA'].apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())
```

Now i would add the mean calculated for the HomeTeam when they played Away and viceversa but i don't find a way to filter it.
Another features i would like to implement would be to choose a number of matches for which choose the rolling mean (for example only 3 last matches home and away)
Anyone can help? Altough it very simple in excel i would like to be able to do it in python because it easier to manage big database...thanks!

This is desired result as requested:
[image]

Comment: why are you doing the `.shift()` at the end of the rolling mean?
also can you provide output example just to understand the target output?

Comment: use shift because i want to exlude the current row, the mean has to be calculated for previous matches, excluding the current one

Comment: Thanks for updating the post, column `desired` consists of which columns exactly? is it `PSCH + HomeMean`(of the  team when they played Away)? it is not clear what equation brought the desired values

Comment: Desired is when HomeTeam played Away  so you have to take the PSCA column for the mean (hope the calc are correct, i did it on the fly :-) ) this is the problem i got trying to filter, actually it is the same as the awaymean but obtained replacing the awayteam with hometeam for the current row

Comment: please check the answer below and let me know if it corresponds to your request.

Comment: Launching your code i got this error: KeyError: "['level_2'] not found in axis"

Comment: just modified the code. could you check it please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254320/discussion-between-eestlane-and-ali-massoud).

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit tricky to get exactly the objective of the question, however, here is a sample code that might help you proceed.
If I understood correctly, your issue is that you couldn't filter out the AwayMeans to add them to the HomeTeams based on the AwayTeams.
Here is a sample could that could get you somewhere closer, feel free to drop some comments to discuss how it can be improved:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

testing = pd.read_excel('Testing.xlsx')

def desire(df):
    means_away = df.groupby(["Season", "AwayTeam"], group_keys=True).PSCA.apply(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift() if x.expanding().mean().shift().notnull().all() else x).reset_index().dropna().drop_duplicates(subset=['AwayTeam'],keep='first').rename(columns={"PSCA": "Desired", "AwayTeam": "HomeTeam"})
    return (
        df
        .merge(means_away, on=["Season", "HomeTeam"], how="left")

    )

finall = (
    testing
    .assign(
        HomeMean= lambda df_: df_.groupby(["Season", "HomeTeam"], group_keys=False).PSCH.apply(lambda x_: x_.expanding().mean().shift()),
        AwayMean= lambda df_: df_.groupby(["Season", "AwayTeam"], group_keys=False).PSCA.apply(lambda x_: x_.expanding().mean().shift())
    )
    .pipe(desire)
)
display(finall)
```

main code is in `means_away` in which I extract the AwayMeans, if I have one row, I keep the same PSCA value, else I take the mean. I drop duplicates and some renaming to prepare for the merge.

your output should be like this:
[image]

I hope this will help!